# Get servletcontext for factory class in spring

Tags: java, spring, servlets

I want to create Factory Class. for example is FooFactory. before Foo instanced, FooFacoty must be injected ServletContext to the constructor. I have snippet as follows:

```
public class FooFactory() {
    public static Foo getFoo() {
        ctx = //getservlet context
        Foo foo = new Foo(ctx);

            return foo;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: You can use `ServletContextFactoryBean`. You can then pass a reference to this into your factory (e.g. as a method argument.). Like this

```
   <bean id="servletContext" class="org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextFactoryBean"/>

   <bean id="foo" class="FooFactory" factory-method="getFoo">
      <constructor-arg index="0" ref="servletContext"/>
   </bean>
```

You then change `FooFactory.getFoo` to

```
   public static Foo getFoo(ServletContext ctx) {
        Foo foo = new Foo(ctx);
        return foo;
   }
```

<strike>There is no direct way that I know of, but you can do it indirectly by implementing ServletContextAware or ApplicationContextAware.</strike>

[This article](http://anydoby.com/jblog/article.htm?id=33) describes the details.

Comment: Note: `ServletContextFactoryBean` is deprecated in Spring 3

Comment: Oh, that's a pitty? Is there an alternative?

Answer (score 3):

I came across this post on my search for how to do this very thing. It helped me as a starting point, but since `ServletContextFactoryBean` is deprecated in Spring 3, I had to try something different.

I found two options:

```
@Autowired
public AnAutowiredConstructor(WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext)
{
    servletContext = webApplicationContext.getServletContext();
}
```

Or you can implement `org.springframework.web.context.ServletContextAware`.

```
public class SomeClass implements ServletContextAware
{
    public void setServletContext(ServletContext servletContext)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can directly inject the instance of ServletContext which is kept by the Spring WebApplicationContext into you bean using xml:

```
<bean id="myBean" class="foo.bar.SomeClass">
    <constructor-arg ref="servletContext"/>
```

Indeed the servlet context is registered in the application context as "servletContext". See http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/WebApplicationContext.html#SERVLET_CONTEXT_BEAN_NAME. Also works with Spring 3.x